# An alternative to the phrase "God bless you"

Tags: figures-of-speech

In the context of wishing someone a Blessing,if I choose not to use the term God , what are the other words that can be used that still conveys the same meaning as the phrase "God bless you"?

Comment: If "God bless you" is used in the context of a very strong "thank you", then "I don't know how I can possibly repay you" is perhaps close enough.

Comment: Same meaning, without "God" or "bless"? Good luck!

Comment: Maybe peace be with you?

Comment: 'I wish you well [in your new job etc].'

Comment: How do you expect someone to confer a wish that the blessings of God be with them without referring to blessings or God?

Comment: You should make clear what the occasion is for dispensing this benediction.  Sneeze or something else?

Comment: May the bird of paradise fly up your nose.

Comment: May some unspecified deity bring benefit to you.

Comment: May you derive benefits from religious superstitions.

Comment: May you continue in your unfounded belief that some supreme being exists, is aware of your existence, and actually cares enough to help you.

Comment: Or, simply, "Peace be with you."

Comment: Or, as a former roommate of mine would say, while making the peace sign, "Peeze on you, señor".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I/We'll be thinking of you.

Take care.

It was great to see you / great talking with you.

Hang in there.

Keep up the good work!

Keep on hangin' on (may be a little old-fashioned now).

Happy *whatever the person said he was going to do* studying, etc. OR Good luck with etc.

Be good.

Talk to you soon.

---

Safe travels.

Comment: None of these (with the possible exception of Good luck with, if you literally believe in luck) seem to meet the question specification "In the context of wishing someone a Blessing"

Answer (score 2):

It's said that "Goodbye" = (May) God be with you!

If you don't wish to say "God bless you", may be you should try "Goodbye" and move on!